# Is it correct to say: "is just this what/all I'll leave behind me?"

Tags: grammaticality

I'd need help from English native speakers to  check the following phrase:
"*A fleeting smile captured on a torn, yellowed snapshot, is just this what/all I'll leave behind me?*" The words "what" or "all" are both ok to me so can be interchangeable.
It should be part of a lyrics so it doesn't need to be polite or formal, just correct.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
thanks to Greybeard and Ammu.

Ok, so it seems that the problem is the word "just". My concern, other that without the "just" word, I have a missing syllable regard the original melody, is that I used the word "just" to emphasize the meaning of the phrase. Is "just" a photo what will survive me once I'll be gone? Does the phrase mantain this meaning without that word and/or is there a way to reprase the whole line in order to keep the meaning and hopefully the number of syllabes? Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be with "just" - its inclusion makes both versions awkward.

Comment: Have you tried "is this just what I'll leave behind me" instead of "is just this"? Or "is this all that I'll leave behind me"? (Actually that last seems to be best to me; but this is actually writing advice — we're writing a song for you.)

Comment: A fleeting smile captured on a torn, yellowed snapshot, is what (all that) I'll leave behind me?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks! Both sound good to me and match the melody. It looks like the problem with the word "just" is the position inside the phrase. Your first solution still has it but as third word instead as second. Is there a rule to explain that?

Comment: @RamPillai: Thanks! I don't understand if the words inside brackets (all that) are alternative to "what" and/or I can use both or just one of them. Sorry, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Marco, I intended to say "A fleeting smile captured on a torn, yellowed snapshot, is what I'll leave behind me." or "A fleeting smile captured on a torn, yellowed snapshot, is all that I'll leave behind me."

Comment: OK, first of all thanks for your help. But the point is: What's the matter with the word "just"? I mean is there a rule I don't know about how to use it in a question phrase? Or in general Is there a rule about how to use this word? I've read your comments, but I didn't understand why my phrase is wrong, why some of you still use "just" in the phrase even if in a different position and why some of you didn't use it at all. Thanks again.